# How can I determine if an Array is readonly using TS compiler-api?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I'd like to determine if an array type is readonly. This includes `ReadonlyArray` and `readonly` prefixed.

Examples:

```
type a = ReadonlyArray<string>
type b = readonly string[]
```

The relevant non-exposed TypeChecker code is:

```
let globalReadonlyArrayType = <GenericType>getGlobalTypeOrUndefined("ReadonlyArray" as __String, /*arity*/ 1) || globalArrayType;

function isReadonlyArrayType(type: Type): boolean {
    return !!(getObjectFlags(type) & ObjectFlags.Reference) && (<TypeReference>type).target === globalReadonlyArrayType;
}

function getGlobalTypeOrUndefined(name: __String, arity = 0): ObjectType | undefined {
    const symbol = getGlobalSymbol(name, SymbolFlags.Type, /*diagnostic*/ undefined); 
    return symbol && <GenericType>getTypeOfGlobalSymbol(symbol, arity);
}

function getTypeOfGlobalSymbol(symbol: Symbol | undefined, arity: number): ObjectType {

    function getTypeDeclaration(symbol: Symbol): Declaration | undefined {
        const declarations = symbol.declarations;
        for (const declaration of declarations) {
            switch (declaration.kind) {
                case SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration:
                case SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration:
                case SyntaxKind.EnumDeclaration:
                    return declaration;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!symbol) {
        return arity ? emptyGenericType : emptyObjectType;
    }
    const type = getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol(symbol);
    if (!(type.flags & TypeFlags.Object)) {
        error(getTypeDeclaration(symbol), Diagnostics.Global_type_0_must_be_a_class_or_interface_type, symbolName(symbol));
        return arity ? emptyGenericType : emptyObjectType;
    }
    if (length((<InterfaceType>type).typeParameters) !== arity) {
        error(getTypeDeclaration(symbol), Diagnostics.Global_type_0_must_have_1_type_parameter_s, symbolName(symbol), arity);
        return arity ? emptyGenericType : emptyObjectType;
    }
    return <ObjectType>type;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TypeChecker Method

[cspotcode](https://github.com/cspotcode) pointed out that you can get `IndexInfo` via the `TypeChecker`.

```
const isReadonlyArrayType = (type: Type) => 
  type.checker.isArrayLikeType(type) &&
  !!type.checker.getIndexInfoOfType(type, IndexKind.Number)?.isReadonly
```

## TS Compiler Method

The following matches the compiler's logic.

```
let globalReadonlyArrayType: Type;

export const isReadonlyArrayType = (type: Type): boolean => {
  const { checker } = type;
  if (!globalReadonlyArrayType) {
    const symbol =
      checker.resolveName('ReadonlyArray', /* location */ void 0, SymbolFlags.Type, /* excludeGlobals */ false)!;
    globalReadonlyArrayType = checker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol(symbol);
  }
  return !!((type as ObjectType).objectFlags & ObjectFlags.Reference) &&
    ((<TypeReference>type).target === globalReadonlyArrayType);
};
```

## Notes

It appears that there may be no immediate advantage of the `TypeChecker` method over using the Compiler method. The one concern that I had was that comparing target equality may fail if `ReadonlyArray` was extended, but it appears that this is currently not possible with TypeScript (v3.9.3)

Logic-wise, if performing `isArrayLikeType` first, the TypeChecker method would be performing a little more work, but likely not enough to worry about in terms of performance.

With that said, it seems that there may be advantage in the TypeChecker method over the second in the event that TS changes its readonly logic, allows extension of ReadonlyArray, etc.

For that reason, I'd recommend using the `TypeChecker` method.

If you're not using [byots](https://npmjs.com/byots/), you could probably replace the call to `isArrayLikeType` with `!!((type as ObjectType).objectFlags & ObjectFlags.Reference)`

**Caveat:** My understanding of `ReadonlyArray` is at a basic level, as of writing this, so if I'm wrong on any of this, please let me know!